# How to split a filename into different parts with VHS in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, fluid

After getting a filename from a folder I would like to split it into parts to show the parts in the Fluid-template.

Filename:
My-super-song_My-Name_1.1.2019.mp3

Should be formatted to HTML like this:

```
<span>My super song</span> recorded by <span>My name</span> at <span>1.1.2019</span>
```

I use a VHS view helper to remove the .mp3 of the file:

```
<v:format.replace substring=".mp3" content="{file.name}" replacement="" count="123"></v:format.replace>
```

Is there any view helper in VHS that could achieve the splitting?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/2.1.2/Iterator/ExplodeViewHelper.html
BTW, this is a question which can be answered just fine in the TYPO3 Slack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mathias Brodola here is the code that is working, many thanks!

```
<v:iterator.explode content="{file.name}" glue="_" as="song">
    <!-- Shows all exploded strings for testing purposes
    <f:for each="{song}" as="iter">
        <pre>{iter}</pre>
    </f:for>
    -->
    <h2>{song.0}</h2>
    <p>Date: 
        <v:format.replace substring=".mp3" content="{song.1}" replacement=""></v:format.replace></p>
</v:iterator.explode>
```